# How to manage a webapp with many DB roles (users) with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jakarta-ee

How to handle the situation where we have a Postgres database running with many database roles (representing the users) and want to use hibernate so every database statement would be executed using a connection fetched with the specific user?

To get a `Session`/`EntityManager` we need to fetch it from an `EntityManagerFactory`, which requires a DB user/password, usually specified in `persistence.xml` like this:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="SYSDBA"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="masterkey"/>
```

Of course i can create a `Session`/`EntityManager` for every user using a separate `EntityManagerFactory`, but this is a costly operation. How can this problem be solved?

Comment: What is the underlying RDBMS?

Comment: I ask that, because Oracle does support changing the schema during a session. `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the RDBMS is PostgreSQL I think the best way to accomplish this would be to call the `SET ROLE` command. This command will change the role and permissions to whatever role is specified. It will carry out all SQL commands during the session as if you logged in with that role in the beginning.

[Here is a link to the Postgres documentation.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set-role.html)

Comment: This way, i still need a table to store my users and their passwords, to make them able to log in to the system, right? (the authentication would be done through the table and the role would be used just for access/write permissions)?

Comment: You manage permissions the standard way PostgreSQL handles roles. You'll need to run a `CREATE ROLE` for each user, and assign permissions.